# Pass data from Console to URL

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, search

When I cklick on a button I get the right data in the console, but now when I click on the button I want that the data 'reid' should pass to the url. When I try:

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('/details/' + this.results.reid);
```

I get undefined back.

[image]

home.page.ts

```
searchName() {
    this.results = this.userService.getName(this.searchTermName).subscribe(result => {
        console.log('Restaurant: ', result);
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/details/' + this.results.reid);
        });
  }
```

home.page.html

```
<ion-grid >
        <ion-row >

            <ion-col size-xs="12" size-sm="12" size-md="8" size-lg="8">
                <ion-searchbar placeholder="Restaurant" [(ngModel)]="searchTermName" ></ion-searchbar>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
</ion-grid>

<div class="btn" >
  <ion-button (click)="searchName()"color="primary" fill="solid">
       suchen
  </ion-button>
</div>
```

user.Service.ts

```
 getName(name1) {
    return this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/searchRestaurantByName', {headers: {name: name1}}).pipe(
        map(name => {
            console.log('RAW: ', name1);
            return name;
        })
    );
  }
```

Comment: It looks like Restaurant is a Array. you need to use the index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`results` is an array, so you should use:

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('/details/' + result[0].reid);
```

Notice that you have a typo, it is `result` not `results` if I see corectly.

Comment: there is no result property to use this.result[0] you mean result[0]

Answer (score 2):

I see that `this.results` is an array of object, its normal that you get `undefined`, 
try to use find wich object first after make your redirect.
for test you can use `result[0].reid` you should get your 39.

Answer (score 2):

this.results is a subscription. It does not contain any 'reid' property.

What you should do is

```
  searchName() {
    this.userService.getName(this.searchTermName)
     .subscribe(result => {
       this.router.navigateByUrl('/details/' + result[0].reid);
     });
  }
```